# How to add jQuery validation to SumoSelect drop downs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sumoselect.js

I am looking for a way to validate multiple sumo select boxes. The code I have is as follows.

**HTML**

```
<select class="kid-age form-select" id="edit-age-big-kid-1" name="age_big_kid_1">     
    <option value="">-</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
</select>

<select class="kid-age form-select" id="edit-age-big-kid-2" name="age_big_kid_2">     
    <option value="">-</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
</select>

<select class="kid-age form-select" id="edit-age-small-kid-1" name="age_small_kid_1">     
    <option value="">-</option>
    <option value="3">0</option>
    <option value="4">1</option>
    <option value="5">2</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
$('.kid-age').SumoSelect();
```

How can I client side validate all of the drop downs (there may be multiple) to be required and display a single message "All kid ages are required."

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check generated code. Plugin creates new html (ul > li structure), so you will have to check for li with class .opt. Selected item gets .selected class, hope it helps... (you will have check text() val)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is quick and simple validation, but it will give you idea, you can modify it to fit your needs:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

   $('.kid-age').SumoSelect();
   $('#submit').on('click', function() {
       errors=[];
       $('p.SelectBox').each(function() {

          if($(this).attr('title')==" -") {



              errors.push('invalid');

          }

       });

        if(errors.length>0) { // if there are errors, show message, stop submission, etc...
               message='All kid ages are required.';
               $('.error').text(message);
          }
          else { //if no errors, continue with script execution...
              $('.error').text('fields validated');
          }
   });


});
```

Plugin creates one specific p tag (for all dropdowns) which holds selected options... so, you can check its value, and if different than ' -', continue script execution, otherwise error will be thrown.

See it in action: https://jsfiddle.net/g7bLbevy/

Comment: Np, glad to help. :)

Comment: It is not a good idea to base your code on internal and undocumented plug-in feature, as it may change in the next release version.

Comment: @MaxZoom, yes, but idea is always the same - check generated html, see what (find element) which plays a role of 'selected option', and use it... better than add options (change plugin) to plugin it self, right? This way, code is, at least, separated from plugin core, and can be easily modified for future uses...

Comment: It seems much easier to do like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/onrg25wf/1/)

Comment: @MaxZoom, post it as an answer :)  i didn't realized that dropdowns (selects) are active, and that values are actually changed, so it is easy to check them :).